# Rails join query with select returning null id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am performing a join query with rails with a select however, the result has null id's for the joined table...

```
@result = Table.joins(:join_table).select(['join_table.id', 'name', 'random_attr', 'created_at']).where('table.random_attr = ?', @anotherresult.id).order('name ASC')
```

The result...

```
[
    {
        random_attr: true
        created_at: "2012-10-31T02:23:07Z"
        id: null
        name: "Joe"
    },
    ....
]
```

The produced sql looks like...

```
SELECT join_table.id, name, random_attr, created_at FROM `table` INNER JOIN `join_table` ON `join_table`.`id` = `table`.`user_id` WHERE (random_attr = 9) ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Doing this query directly in mysql works fine.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by grabbing matching field from the other table but I would still like to know why the id would be null.

Comment: why your where clause `'table.random_attr = ?', @anotherresult.id` compare a true/false with an integer id?